# Back button does not light-up when I press home button

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-y

I bought a Samsung Galaxy Y phone yesterday. I was wondering why the `Back` button does not light up when I press `Home` button on the device.

On my Samsung Galaxy Ace the `Back` button and `Menu` button light up immediately whenever I press home button.

Is there a setting associated with this that I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galaxy Y GT-S5360 simply does not have backlighting for its capacitive buttons ([source 1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1682277), [source 2](http://tech2.in.com/reviews/smartphones/samsung-galaxy-y-gts5360-review/273722)) whereas the Ace does - there is nothing you can do.